# How to create Pandas dataframe of given values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

With the following code I get:

```
import pandas as pd

date=['1/3/15','2/5/15','3/6/15','4/8/16']
dist=[5,4,11,12]
dd=list(zip(date,dist))
df=pd.DataFrame(dd,columns=['Date','Dist'])
print(df)
```

out:

```
Date  Dist
0  1/3/15     5
1  2/5/15     4
2  3/6/15    11
3  4/8/16    12
```

I would like to be able to get only the dist > 10 and the corresponding date as so:

```
Date  Dist
2  3/6/15  11
3  4/8/16  12
```

I've tried the following:

```
dd10=pd.DataFrame(df['Dist']>10)
print(dd10)
```

Which only results in:

```
0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
Name: Dist, dtype: bool
```

How can I get the desired result as an int. with the corresponding date instead of a bool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and need `df[mask]`:

```
df1 = df[df['Dist']>10]
```

Another way for filtering is [`DataFrame.query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
df1 = df.query("Dist > 10")
```

---

```
print (df1)
     Date  Dist
2  3/6/15    11
3  4/8/16    12
```